# mysql_insert_id() is not working

Tags: php, mysql

I want to show last inserted data from MySQL row. But if I use `mysql_insert_id()` it not worked. But if I use without `id='$id` that means   `$sql="SELECT * FROM $table WHERE creator='$creator'";` it worked. But not select in last row. How can I show Last inserted data?

```
<?php @session_start(); ?>
<?php include "header.php"?>
<?php include "db.php"?>
<?php
                        $table="signup";
                        $creator=$_SESSION["id"];
                        $id = mysql_insert_id();
                        $sql="SELECT * FROM $table WHERE id='$id' AND creator='$creator'";                      
                        $result=mysql_query($sql);
                        $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);

?>


   <p>Name: <?php echo $row['name']; ?></p>
   <p>Email: <?php echo $row['email']; ?></p>
   <p>ID: <h2><span class="star "><?php echo $row['id']; ?></span></h2></p>
```

Comment: mysql_insert_id() returns after an insert query not a select. BTW mysql is deprecated you should use mysqli or PDO

Comment: using mysql_ is evil! use mysqli_ or PDO instead!

Comment: possible duplicate of [mysql\_insert\_id(); not returning value after successful row insert](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12775338/mysql-insert-id-not-returning-value-after-successful-row-insert)

Comment: "It not worked"? Why don't you explain _precisely_ what happened?

Comment: +1 because there's no logical way you could have determined this from the PHP manual. @Yoel: No, the two questions are _completely_ different. This one doesn't even perform an insert at all.

Answer (score 3):

**[`mysql_insert_id`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-insert-id.php) is calculated on a per-connection basis.**

The PHP manual doesn't bother to state this, but you're indirectly using the MySQL API and [the MySQL documentation for `mysql_insert_id`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysql-insert-id.html) is very clear:

> The value of `mysql_insert_id()` is affected only by statements issued within the current client connection. It is not affected by statements issued by other clients.

This feature prevents race conditions where you `INSERT` in one script instance while someone else `INSERT`s at the same time in another, and you wouldn't know what you were getting from `last_insert_id`. ([reference](http://kera.name/articles/2011/08/one-less-bug-to-worry-about/))

However, that also means that you cannot just run it in a script without having executed an `INSERT` at all. It is actually not possible to use this technique to get the ID of the last inserted row when it wasn't *you* who inserted that row. From PHP and MySQL's point of view, you are a different person to the person who ran the script last time!

The best you can do in this instance, so far as I can tell, is to perform a `SELECT` to find the highest ID in the extant data, and hope that this is what you wanted. Alternatively, *in the code that performs the `INSERT`*, store the result of `mysql_insert_id()` in a session variable and use that here.

Without having been told what you're actually trying to do, I can't suggest anything further.

Answer (score -2):

correct usage of `mysql_insert_id` (using details from the question) is:

```
      $sql="INSERT INTO ".$table." (creator)  VALUES ('$creator')"; 
    mysql_query($sql);
    $id = mysql_insert_id();
```

$id returns the value of the last insert statement.

Comment: He doesn't want to `INSERT` anything.

Comment: I was showing the correct usage of the `mysql_insert_id` , as that is the original question. weather he wants to insert or not is fairly unimportant

Comment: It may not be important to _you_, but I'm guessing it's fairly important to _him_. "Here, use some code that does something completely different than what you want to do" is not helpful. The question is _not_ "how to do correct use of `mysql_insert_id`?"; it is "how do I do want I want to do?" Thanks.

Comment: with all due respect, that's for him to decide. The question was about this specific function, it was not about how his SELECT statement was not returning a mysql_insert_id value. He was using the function completely out of its intended context so I wrote an example to should what context the function _would_ work in. He can learn from that and adapt his code accordingly.

Comment: ​​​​​​​​: That's absurd. What do you suggest he inserts into the database, then? Magic fairy dust? _His application does not do that!_ I don't know how to make it any clearer. Oh well.

Comment: Welcome to the 90's. I hope you enjoy your SQL injections.

Comment: wow, easy there Lightness - I'm not suggesting he inserts anything into the database, I am showing in a few lines example - using details he's already posted - what `mysql_insert_id` is _intended_ to do, he can then take that knowledge and apply it to his script however he wants to.

Comment: @Martin: ... which is completely useless, because he doesn't want to insert anything within this particular script. So showing him how to use `mysql_insert_id` with an `INSERT` is not helpful to even the slightest degree. It's literally the opposite of the correct answer. What he needs is an _alternative_ to `mysql_insert_id`! And an explanation as to why his code currently does not work.

Comment: his question was **mysql_insert_id() is not working** and so I showed how this function is _intended_ to work, using code that can be directly related to from the question, I did not go into his specific situation, because if anyone else reads this question with similar issues as to the question title they will not be in this specific situation, but searching Google or SO for details on `mysql_insert_id`. There are two subjects, of answering a question and fixing an OPs code within, and these two subjects do not always totally correlate.

Comment: You didn't fix the OP's code, _and_ you did not answer the question! Other than that, yeah great. If your intent was to just point out that an `INSERT` must be previously performed within the same script, and not to go any further than that, then that is fine but you didn't do that: just posting an unrelated code example without _explaining_ the problem is insufficient. But it doesn't matter because I did it in my answer.

Comment: BTW if you're holding this code up as an example of "how this function is _intended_ to work", then you failed also because there is no error checking in your example.